# Error at Extension Manager

Tags: magento2

in Extension Manager i get this error:

`Command "show" failed: Failed to clone the git@github.com:i-ways/magento2-paypal-plus.git repository, try running in interactive mode so that you can enter your GitHub credentials In Git.php line 354: Failed to execute git clone --mirror 'git@github.com:i-ways/magento2-paypal -plus.git'`

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Confirm that you have configured `composer.json` correctly

> To install the Magento 2 PayPal PLUS extension please add our
> repository to your Magento composer.json.

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "url": "https://github.com/i-ways/magento2-paypal-plus",
            "type": "vcs"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then run the command `composer require iways/module-pay-pal-plus` as per the installation instructions : https://github.com/i-ways/magento2-paypal-plus

You may also need to configure your `auth.json` with github authentication credentials

```
  "github-oauth": {
    "github.com": "123ABC"
  }
```

See the following documentation for creating an auth token :
https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token